# TypeORM looping on WhereExpressionBuilder result same value

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a problem, I need to show all the rows containing certain tags.
on the database tags format like `one,two,three`

here my WhereExpressionBuilder code.

```
        const tags = ['one','twoo','three']

        new Brackets(qb => {
          tags.forEach((tag, i) => {
            i === 0 ? qb = qb.where('tags LIKE :tag', { tag: `%${tag}%` }) : qb = qb.orWhere('tags LIKE :tag', { tag: `%${tag}%` })
          })
          return qb;
        }),
```

here the query result

```
[
  'SELECT ... WHERE id IS NOT NULL AND (tags LIKE ? OR tags LIKE ? OR tags LIKE ?)',
  [ '%three%', '%three%', '%three%' ]
]
```

that not as expected, any have a good idea to solve this, or their best wat to do.

thanks

Answer (score -1):

Since PostgreSQL supports [POSIX regular expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP), you could simply write a query like the following:

```sql
select * from table where tags ~* 'foo|bar|baz';
```

This is the easiest way to achieve the expected behavior.

Comment: that is not what I am looking for, it's easy if all using raw SQL, but I looking for using typeORM solution. anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: I see, problably TypeORM (or even any ORM) doesn't have an easy way to do it. Usually when you need a more "complex" query the ORM suggests using raw SQL or the query builder

Comment: yes, currently I am using raw SQL, but it's not safe for MySQL injection.